# DropDown not displaying what was previously selected & saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The customer can view their cust details page where they can change their pre-recorded delivery run (if they wish too) I have a drop down list containing towns for delivery runs:

```
<div class="editor-label">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryRunList, Model.DeliveryRunList)</div>
```

When the customer profile loads it displays the correct town in the drop down(reading from the DB, which they previously selected when registering).

However if they change the town and save it, the user is returned to the home page and the newly selected tow is saved to the DB. But, if the user returns to the customer profile page the drop down displays the previously selected town, as opposed to the new one just previously selected and saved to the DB.  Is it being stored in the cache somewhere.

Why is it not updating to what is actually in the DB??

Codebehind:

```
CustomerPart custPart = _custService.Get(custId);

if (DeliveryRunList.HasValue)
{
    custPart.DeliveryRun_Id = DeliveryRunList.Value;
}

_custService.Update(custPart);
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you just need to populate it when the page is loaded. Get the customers town and set the selected index of the dropdown = the town value (assuming you are binding on the town id/town text for data and text fields)

Comment: Have you debugged that statement to make sure the update is actually happening... I would think that if you model bind the existing value to the drop down list then it will always have a value...

Comment: Please post the code that defines the DeliveryRunList.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `model` is a CustomerPart instance, and you have defined it more or less in this way.

```
public class CustomerPart
{
    public int DeliveryRun_Id {get; set;}
    public SelectList(or some IEnumerable) DeliveryRun_Id
}
```

I feel your code isn't updating the DB since you use the wrong attributes. The first lambda expression should be `model => model.TheAttributeYouWantToUpdate`, in this case `DeliveryRun_Id`.

So it should be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryRun_Id, Model.DeliveryRunList)
```

rather than

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryRunList, Model.DeliveryRunList)
```

It's not even clear where is this code inside the controller:

```
CustomerPart custPart = _custService.Get(custId);

if (DeliveryRunList.HasValue)
{
    custPart.DeliveryRun_Id = DeliveryRunList.Value;
}

_custService.Update(custPart);
```

A common way of doing it is to have two methods of the same name for editing, one for HttpGet and one for HttpPost, and use a `@Html.BeginForm()` in the razor view for updating, rather than updating the info in controller.

Example:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0) {
            InvestmentFund Fund = InvestmentFundData.GetFund(id);
            return Fund == null ? (ActionResult)HttpNotFound() : View(Fund);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(InvestmentFund Fund)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                InvestmentFundData.Update(Fund);
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
            return View(Fund);
        }
```

In View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @* For the attributes of your model *@
        @Html.LabelFor ... 
        @Html.EditorFor ...
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor ...

        <input type="Submit"m value="Save">
    }
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to give me a detailed reply...that did solve the initial problem...now the correct delivery run will display when the page is loaded. however new problem is: if the user tries to 'save' the page, deliveryRunRecord.Id returns as NULL and throws the Object reference not set to an instance of an object....any idea?

Comment: I have no idea what deliveryRunRecord is. You'd better open a new quesiton and provide more details about your program. See http://sscce.org/ .